# How to setup SSH access to Arch Linux Iso (livecd) booted computer?

Tags: arch-linux, sshd, live-usb, livecd

How to setup/configure the Arch Linux bootcd (live-CD, ISO) so I can login to it using an SSH client?

And which password is by default set for the (automatic login) root account?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default root password for the ISO distribution is blank. And by default you are not allowed to login with SSH using a blank password.

Therefore two commands are necessary:

1. **`passwd`**  --
   To set a non blank password for the currently logged in user ('root' for liveCD). Enter the password *twice*.
2. *Before september 2021:* **`systemctl start sshd.service`** --
   To start the ssh daemon.

   *September 2021 and later:* sshd is started by default.

Now you can login from your client machine using `ssh root@ip-address`.

---

PS Don't know the IP address? The live-CD includes commands `ifconfig` and `ip address`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to

- [install Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) onto an USB stick/harddisk (you can do this from the live cd)
- in the new installation

  - set a root password (`passwd`)
  - allow ssh root login (`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and append `PermitRootLogin yes`)
  - enable sshd (`systemctl enable sshd`)
  - also don't forget to enable systemd-networkd anything else you may need (like to preconfigure wifi)
- boot the new machine from the usb device

Comment: The question is asking only for a solution for the live-CD (ISO) boot. installing onto USB stick/harddisk is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @ProBackup this answer is for people who are trying to install arch on a system without a display/keyboard